# Create directives dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm quite new to AngularJS. I think I have studied most of the basics. I want to create sort of a desktop with the items shown on the desktop dynamically loaded from a database via $http. For the items I have created a directive that wraps the display of a title and an icon. Now my problem is that I don't know how to create the directive instances dynamically. My controller looks like this:

```
$scope.loadItems = function () {
    $http.get('api/StartcenterItems').
    success(function (data) {
        var itemsContainer =  angular.element(document.querySelector("#itemsContainer"));

        for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; ++i) {
            itemsContainer.append('<hl-start-center-item title="Test"></hl-start-center-item>');
        }
    }).
    error(function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

where hl-start-center-item is the directive. The problem is that the html code for the directive gets appended but it gets not compiled by Angular and is not displayed by the browser. What do I have to do to make the directive correctly displayed?
If you need more code to reproduce the problem please tell me.

Thanks for any idea,
Nicolas

Comment: Can you add your directive code and better if you can add HTML also to get and idea how you done this

Comment: @NicolasR: There is obviously still a lot to learn about Angular basics. Most importantly: it's not jQuery ! (You need to `$compile` and link the HTML to achieve what you want, but that is the least of your problems...)

Comment: @Seminda. Thanks for your reply, see my comment to CaspNZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good place to use an `ngRepeat` directive.

In your main HTML:

```
<div id="itemsContainer">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data >
        <hl-start-center-item title="Test"></hl-start-center-item>
    </div>
</div>
```

As long as you assign your results to data inside the digest cycle, it should update by generating your directives.

Your success function would look something like this:

```
success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    }
}).
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it!!! Actually I had it like this with a static array of items. I unneccessarily changed it to the code I posted when I switched to loading the items dynamically. What I forgot, was that $scope.data = data will automatically recompile the html. Very comfortable. Thanks again.